# Fetching data from an API using the Fetch API in HTML with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, api, fetch-api

Hey I am struggling to fetch an API. I just don't get it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sponsorkliks API Table</title>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: left;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    th {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="api-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Logo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>

  <script>
    fetch('https://www.sponsorkliks.com/api/?club=11592&call=webshops_club_extension')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const tableBody = document.querySelector('#api-table tbody');
        data.forEach(item => {
          const row = document.createElement('tr');
          const nameCell = document.createElement('td');
          nameCell.textContent = item.name;
          row.appendChild(nameCell);
          const urlCell = document.createElement('td');
          const urlLink = document.createElement('a');
          urlLink.href = item.url;
          urlLink.textContent = item.url;
          urlCell.appendChild(urlLink);
          row.appendChild(urlCell);
          const logoCell = document.createElement('td');
          const logoImg = document.createElement('img');
          logoImg.src = item.logo;
          logoImg.alt = item.name;
          logoImg.style.maxWidth = '100px'; // adjust size if needed
          logoCell.appendChild(logoImg);
          row.appendChild(logoCell);
          tableBody.appendChild(row);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to use the API above and would like to take data out if it. However, everything I tried so far did not work.

I tried a lot of different things to fetch the data. I have nevert worked with this before, so I can not figure it out.

Comment: and what does "not work" mean?

Comment: `data.webshops.forEach(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just not so focused on your data. You should iterate `data.webshops` and use different field names in a webshop object:

```js
    fetch('https://www.sponsorkliks.com/api/?club=11592&call=webshops_club_extension')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({webshops}) => {
        const tableBody = document.querySelector('#api-table tbody');
        webshops.forEach(item => {
          const row = document.createElement('tr');
          const nameCell = document.createElement('td');
          nameCell.textContent = item.name_short;
          row.appendChild(nameCell);
          const urlCell = document.createElement('td');
          const urlLink = document.createElement('a');
          urlLink.href = item.link;
          urlLink.textContent = item.orig_url;
          urlCell.appendChild(urlLink);
          row.appendChild(urlCell);
          const logoCell = document.createElement('td');
          const logoImg = document.createElement('img');
          logoImg.src = item.logo_120x60;
          logoImg.alt = item.name_short;
          logoImg.style.maxWidth = '100px'; // adjust size if needed
          logoCell.appendChild(logoImg);
          row.appendChild(logoCell);
          tableBody.appendChild(row);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

```css
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: left;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    th {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
```

```html
  <table id="api-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Logo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
```

I also don't recommend adding elements with DOM, it's slow, use pure html:

```js
fetch('https://www.sponsorkliks.com/api/?club=11592&call=webshops_club_extension')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({webshops}) => {
        document.querySelector('#api-table tbody').innerHTML = 
          webshops.map(item => 
          `<tr>
            <td>${item.name_short}</td>
            <td><a href="${item.link}">${item.orig_url}</td>
            <td>
              <img src="${item.logo_120x60}" 
                style="max-width:100px"
                alt="${item.name_short}">
            </td>
          </tr>`
          ).join('')
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

```css
table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: left;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    th {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
```

```html
<table id="api-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>URL</th>
        <th>Logo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! It worked and I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Jordy you're welcome, i've added you to my whitelist to help you in the future

Comment: I have a question regarding your code: there is a comma between all the rows in the output. Is it possible to get rid of those commas?

Comment: @Jordy sorry my bad! it's because i forgot Array::join('') to join the rows with an empty string. fixed!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that data is supposed to be an array, but instead is an `Object {webshops: Array(694)}`. Change `data.foreach(item => {` to `Object.values(item => {`. Then, loop through each of the arrays inside of the object and grab the data. However, while doing this, a I realized the objects take the form of `Object {category: "Gifts", name_short: "Sinterklaas-feestwinkel.nl", name_long: "Sinterklaas-feestwinkel.nl", description: "De Sinterklaas-feestwinkel.nl is er voor alle Sinterklaas inkopen, naast een grote assortiment Sinterklaas versiering en Sinterklaas en Zwarte pieten kostuums heeft deze winkel ook kado’s voor jong en oud. Hier vindt men alles voor een geslaagde Sinterklaas avond.", logo_120x60: "https://www.sponsorkliks.com/gfx/partners/sinterklaas-feestwinkel.png", …}`, so I think you were mistaken when you wrote url. Instead of url, I swapped it out for 'description', as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sponsorkliks API Table</title>
  <style>
    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }
    th, td {
      padding: 8px;
      text-align: left;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    th {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="api-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Logo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>

  <script>
    fetch('https://www.sponsorkliks.com/api/?club=11592&call=webshops_club_extension')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        const tableBody = document.querySelector('#api-table tbody');
        Object.values(data).forEach(item => {
          item.forEach((item) => {
            const row = document.createElement('tr');
            const nameCell = document.createElement('td');
            nameCell.textContent = item.name_short;
            row.appendChild(nameCell);
            const descriptionCell = document.createElement('td');
            const description = document.createElement('div');
            description.innerHTML = item.description;
            descriptionCell.appendChild(description);
            row.appendChild(descriptionCell);
            const logoCell = document.createElement('td');
            const logoImg = document.createElement('img');
            logoImg.src = item.logo_120x60;
            logoImg.alt = item.name_short;
            logoImg.style.maxWidth = '100px'; // adjust size if needed
            logoCell.appendChild(logoImg);
            row.appendChild(logoCell);
            tableBody.appendChild(row);
          });
        });
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, watch out, since I disabled script escaping, so if the api has a hidden `<script>` tag, it would run and this would result in a code injection attack.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize the url was hidden inside the Object...

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! It worked and I really appreciate your help!